# armv8 changing exception level from el2 to el1

Tags: exception, arm, uefi

I am trying to write simple efi application that change the exception level from el2 64bit to el1 64 bit but with no success.

```
void entry_el1(void){
    Print (L"running in el1.\n\r");
}

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
UefiMain (
  IN EFI_HANDLE        ImageHandle,
  IN EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE  *SystemTable
  )
{   


    __asm__ volatile (
    "mov x0, #(1 << 31)\n\t"
    "msr hcr_el2, x0\n\t"

    "mov x0, #0x0800\n\t"
    "movk x0, #0x30d0, lsl #16\n\t"
    "msr sctlr_el1, x0\n\t"

    "mov x0, #0x33ff\n\t"
    "msr cptr_el2, x0\n\t"

    "msr hstr_el2, xzr\n\t"

    "mov x0, #0x3c5\n\t" 
    "msr spsr_el2, x0\n\t"

    "mov x0, %0\n\t"  
    "msr elr_el2, x0\n\t"

    "eret" : : "r" (entry_el1) :
    );

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

After running this nothing happens! Is this the correct procedure for changing exception level?

Comment: First and most obvious, check your disassembly; what's to stop the compiler passing `%0` in `x0`? Also, I know very little about EDK2, and nothing about other UEFI implementations, so this may be hypothetical, but is that EL2 address still going to be valid at EL1 (i.e. what's the MMU setup at this point)? Conversely, do you know for sure that it hasn't actually worked and just crashed afterwards trying to return at the wrong EL, without an output buffer being flushed?

Comment: As far as I know, the application started in EL2 with identity mapping. The MMU is off for both stage in EL1 so the return address should be valid. Almost similar code is used in Linux in "el2_setup" function ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's not simply the lack of a clobber list on the inline asm causing your ELR_EL2 address to get trashed (in which case skip straight to "triggers an exception" below), I reckon you're dropping to EL1 just fine; it's when you get there that the trouble starts...

As a non-leaf C function, the first thing `entry_el1` is going to do is push a return address to the stack (or if the compiler's been clever enough to optimise it into a tail call with no stack frame, then the prologue of `Print` is the guy doing that, but same thing). Except we're in handler mode (EL1h), which means that unless anyone's been messing with SPSel then our stack pointer is SP_EL1, which at this point probably contains uninitialised nonsense. Thus the stack access almost certainly triggers an exception, but we're at EL1, so that exception is taken to the vectors pointed to by VBAR_EL1, which at this point probably contains uninitialised nonsense. Hello there, lockup death by recursive exception.

If you're comparing with the Linux entry code, then it's important to note that when (if) that drops down from EL2, it's still going into more bare-metal assembly code that sets EL1 up from scratch before it gets anywhere near C code - indeed, setting up a stack pointer at all is one of the very *last* things it does.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder! I was concern so much with the inline assembly and totally forgot the C function call conventions. I replaced it with a bare-metal assembly and now its works!